# Using service accounts and oauth2 to call autoML Google API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, automl, google-cloud-iam

I've trained an image classification model using autoML API and now I would like to create a JAVA program that makes predictions of given images using that model. As mentioned in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models/predict), this API requires the OAuth scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.

I don't need the user to login since I will not use any private data, so I decided to use service accounts and followed the steps in [OAuth2 for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) to generate an access token.

The process goes well and I receive the reponse:

```
    {"access_token": "access_token_string", "expires_in": 3600, "token_type": "Bearer"}
```

Then, I go back to send the post request for autoML prediction, and set the header "Authorization" to "Bearer access_token_string".
I have the error message

```
{"error": 
   {
   "code": 403,
   "message": "The caller does not have permission",
   "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
   }
}
```

I know that the prediction request is correct because I've tried it using an accessToken generated for web apps (just wanted to test).
So the problem is in the authorization part, I've checked that my service account have all the required permissions as well. I d'ont know where the problem is exactly, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So since there are no answers, I contacted the Google Support Service, they told me that the below requests are correct, the problem is in allowing the service account to access my GCP project resources. This step is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/before-you-begin)

I've already went through this step but I should have missed something the first time, so I deleted the service account and restarted all the steps, it's working now!
I hope this will help someone :)